# How to make a VM instance running sneakily as if it is a remote server?

Tags: virtualbox

Both host and vm are xubuntu 12.04.
I know that `VBoxManage startvm "name"` will start a VM from command line but the GUI will pop up anyway. Is there a way to start this vm and make it running sneakily at the background? Thus I can access it as if it is a server. Previously I let the GUI up and do my job via the console of the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless`